# How do I preserve list names when working with nested lists?

Tags: r, plyr

The advantage of using `plyr`'s `llply` over `lapply` is that it preserves list names. See `?llply` for an explanation. I love that feature but cannot seem to get it to work in the case of a nested list. Example:

```
library(plyr) 
m <- as.list(1:2)
names(m) <- c('M1', 'M2')
foo <- list(m, m)
names(foo) <- paste0("R", 1:2)


result <- ldply(foo, function(x){
        ldply(x, function(z) { data.frame(a=z, b= z^2)})
})
> result
  .id a b
1  M1 1 1
2  M2 2 4
3  M1 1 1
4  M2 2 4

# if I don't operate on the inner list, I can preserve the outer list's names
result2 <- ldply(foo, function(x){
     data.frame(a = x[[1]], b = x[[1]]^2)
    })
> result2
  .id a b
1  R1 1 1
2  R2 1 1
```

Note that `result` does not contain `R1` and `R2` (which would get added in as `.id` if I didn't operate on the nested list inside each element of `foo` as is the case with `result2`). How do I make sure I get the outer list names added in when working on nested lists?

Comment: Note: I'm aware that I could fix this posthoc (as in read the names from foo and replicate each one by the length of sublists and add that as a new column). But I'm hoping to understand why I can't get `llply` to function as designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the column name is the problem:

```
result <- ldply(foo, function(x){
    df <- ldply(x, function(z) { data.frame(a=z, b= z^2)})
    names(df)[1] <- ".id2"; df
})
result
  .id .id2 a b
1  R1   M1 1 1
2  R1   M2 2 4
3  R2   M1 1 1
4  R2   M2 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks, good catch. I wonder if I should post this as a bug for plyr. It would be a quick fix to check to see if a column named `.id` exists and just create a new one.

Comment: Yes, please file a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `ldply` does not assign to the `.id` variable if there is already one.  If you look at the results of one of your inner `ldply` once, it is fine:

```
> ldply(foo[[1]], function(z) { data.frame(a=z, b= z^2)})
  .id a b
1  M1 1 1
2  M2 2 4
```

Rename it out of the way and it works as expected.

```
result <- ldply(foo, function(x){
    rename(ldply(x, function(z) { data.frame(a=z, b= z^2)}),
           c(".id" = ".id2"))
})
```

gives

```
> result
  .id .id2 a b
1  R1   M1 1 1
2  R1   M2 2 4
3  R2   M1 1 1
4  R2   M2 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, looks like you and Julius figured the same solution. cheers.